# Merging domain extensions of .com and .in but displaying .com in the URL Bar

Tags: php, dns, nameservers

I am developing a web application and have bought two domain names `xxx.com` and `xxx.in`. While coding for the new website, I have been using `xxx.in`, while keeping `xxx.com` for the old website. During the coding process, I have hardcoded `xxx.in` in some places. Now that my new website is ready for deployment, I want to change its domain to `xxx.com`. It would be better if there is some sort of redirect from `.in` to `.com` so that the user gets to see only `.com` in the URL bar while allowing my codes to run perfectly. Is this possible by just creating an A Rule in my host? How should I proceed in such a situation?

Comment: Stop hard coding domains. Make it a configuration setting somewhere. You can redirect `example.in` to `example.com`, but that's an inefficient way of handling this (two HTTP requests for everything).

Comment: Use fulltext search to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should proceed by either:

**Option 1: fast and easy (but not optimal) -**

Use search and replace to turn all instances of 'xxx.in' to 'xxx.com'

**Option 2: the better way to go -**

Use search and replace to turn all instances of 'xxx.in' to some kind of helper function to retrieve a configuration value for your domain. For example:

```
MyHelper::getConfig('baseUrl');
```

... or similar

Then, create your helper class and the necessary functions to grab this configuration value out of your database.